# How to change TO option in Outgoing email setup

Tags: wordpress, email, installation, testing

Newbie here. I've just installed CiviCRM in a Wordpress site and am currently configuring. When setting up the outbound email, it propagates this "TO" address. This address doesn't exist and I don't know where to change it to a live address. Would someone please point me in the direction of where to change the default "TO" address that appears here?

[image]

Comment: it is likely to be the email on the contact record that connects to the user you are logged in as. have you just done a civi search for that email?

Comment: Pete, can you convert your comment into answer?

Comment: Thank you @petednz-fuzion. I wondered if that might be where the erroneous info was being picked up. It seems the addy was added as a contact when I installed the app. I changed the addy to the correct addy and now the email is going through.

Comment: cool. Cabriolet, pls accept and +1 the answer below

Answer (score 1):

The email will be the one on the contact record that connects to the user you are logged in as.